# how to disable default selection in dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want the code to disable default selection in dropdownlist in asp.net and also on selection of a particular data field the values are displayed in the txtbox below.the dropdown should be filled with system related data like eg c:drive, d ... etc dynamically at run time.

Comment: can u be specific ?...I dont get anything from "to disable default selection in dropdownlist" ..and what kind of data u want to come inside dropDown ?

Comment: Please update the question with details on how you populate the combobox. Is it databound or not? What is the data source? Where should the system related data come from? The server? The client?

Comment: by default, the selection of a dropdownlist is empty iirc

Comment: @Levisaxos: that depends on how it's populated. If it is databound, it defaults to the first item I think.

Comment: i want to display system data ie drives name in dropdownlist and on selection of any drive, its related information sud be displayed in the txtbox. and if the first data in dropdownlist is C, thn by default in my code C is being shown in the dropdown, which i dont want

Comment: system related data comes from server

Comment: Check this: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial233_Getting-Disk-Drive-Information-using-WMI-and-Csharp.html, It is windows forms but the concept will remain same with asp.net dropdownlist.

Comment: How you are binding your data can you tell

Answer (score 1):

then you can manually append ""--select--"" in the first place in the dropdownlist by edit items. and set appenddatabounditems to true.. thus you will get select in the first place rather than the first drive by default......
ok then use this function and cal this function on the databound event of dropdownlist.

```
void RemoveDuplicateItems(DropDownList ddl)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ddl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            ddl.SelectedIndex = i;
            string str = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
            for (int counter = i + 1; counter < ddl.Items.Count; counter++)
            {
                ddl.SelectedIndex = counter;
                string compareStr = ddl.SelectedItem.ToString();
                if (str == compareStr)
                {
                    ddl.Items.RemoveAt(counter);
                   counter = counter - 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and call this function in dropdownlist_databound() event.

Answer (score 0):

then you can manually append ""--select--"" in the first place in the dropdownlist by edit items. and set appenddatabounditems to true.. thus you will get select in the first place rather than the first drive by default......

Comment: i have done the necessary changes as u told. but the problem now is aftr selecting a particular drive it is going again in page load
and all the options along with select are being repeated. inorder to avoid this what should i do?

Comment: @nikita: You should share your code so we can point out what is wrong. The reason for duplicate values is because your DDL is getting databound upon every postback.

Comment: @nikita i gave you the coding to stop duplicate values. does it work?

Comment: i think she also needs to code this on (!IsPostback). So that it will not reload again and again